# decodebin2 data internal error inside videomixer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to create an image vector with Gstreamer. To do that I use the videomixer gref like that :

```
gst-launch -e \videomixer name = mixer \
 sink_0::xpos = 0 sink_0::ypos = 0 \
 sink_1::xpos = 100 sink_1::ypos = 0 \
 sink_2::xpos = 200 sink_2::ypos = 0 \
 sink_3::xpos = 300 sink_3::ypos = 0 \
 sink_4::xpos = 400 sink_4::ypos = 0 \
 sink_5::xpos = 500 sink_5::ypos = 0 \
 sink_6::xpos = 600 sink_6::ypos = 0 \
 sink_7::xpos = 700 sink_7::ypos = 0 \
 sink_8::xpos = 0 sink_8::ypos = 0  \
! xvimagesink \
filesrc location = 0.jpg \
! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace  \
! imagefreeze ! videoscale method = 1 ! video/x-raw-yuv, width = 100, height = 100 ! mixer.sink_0. \
filesrc location = 1.jpeg \
! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace  \
! imagefreeze ! videoscale method = 1 ! video/x-raw-yuv, width = 100, height = 100 ! mixer.sink_1. \
filesrc location = 2.png \
! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace  \
! imagefreeze ! videoscale method = 1 ! video/x-raw-yuv, width = 100, height = 100 ! mixer.sink_2. \
filesrc location = 3.png \
! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace  \
! imagefreeze ! videoscale method = 1 ! video/x-raw-yuv, width = 100, height = 100 ! mixer.sink_3. \
filesrc location = 4.png \
! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace  \
! imagefreeze ! videoscale method = 1 ! video/x-raw-yuv, width = 100, height = 100 ! mixer.sink_4. \
filesrc location = 5.png \
! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace  \
! imagefreeze ! videoscale method = 1 ! video/x-raw-yuv, width = 100, height = 100 ! mixer.sink_5. \
filesrc location = 6.JPG \
! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace  \
! imagefreeze ! videoscale method = 1 ! video/x-raw-yuv, width = 100, height = 100 ! mixer.sink_6. \
filesrc location = 7.png \
! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace  \
! imagefreeze ! videoscale method = 1 ! video/x-raw-yuv, width = 100, height = 100 ! mixer.sink_7. \
filesrc location = bg.jpg \
! decodebin2 ! ffmpegcolorspace \
! imagefreeze ! mixer.sink_8.
```

But I've a problem, it's seems to work with only several type of image (very often with .png, but not with .jpg for example). I d'ont understand, decodebin is supposed to be independant of the file format, isn't it ?
I tried to put the same png file for each element of the vector and it's ok, so what's wrong ? I've the following error : "Data stream internal error".

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks !

(Sorry about my english, I'm french)

Comment: When you receive the error, do you receive any other output?  Even if it looks harmless, it may help someone track down the error.  Also, try running gst-launch with the --verbose flag, it may give more information as well.

Answer (score 0):

firstly which gstreamer version are you using? (0.10 or 1.0).
If you use 0.10, I recommand you to use videomixer2.

videomixer is very sensitive about the input format, so I recommande you to add in each input pad of videomixer a specific format in your caps something like that 
"video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)AYUV, width=100, height=100"

If you don't have a transparency PNG I will advice to use this one:
"video/x-raw-yuv, format=(fourcc)I420, width=100, height=100"
It's should be works